# Educational DOS game involving teddy bears

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-game

I remember when I was very young (mid-to-late 90s) playing a probably educational DOS game that was like a whole bunch of minigames. At least one of the minigames (perhaps all of them) was teddy-bear-themed. There was one involving maths, one involving a train, one involving books in a shelf (I think I remember the background graphics showing a few books on the floor which always annoyed me), and maybe there was a paint-like program I think as well. Some of this stuff might be me conflating multiple different games but I think at least most of it was from this game. I'm in the UK if that matters.

Comment: Can you say anything about the type of gameplay? Was it a platform 2D scroller, top-down scroller, or a first-person 3D game like Wolfenstein 3D and friends, or what?

Comment: As I said, it was a collection of minigames, and I think they were all just basic educational puzzles. Things like you have to click on (or perhaps type? I can't even remember if we had a mouse! Though I suppose if my memory of the paint program was accurate we must have done) the answer to a maths question, or there was probably something to do with words. I'm mostly asking because it's been bugging me at the back of my head for some time; I don't expect to be wowed by the amazing gameplay!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly the Fun School series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun_School

They were popular when I was at school in the UK, early 90s. We played them on Amiga 500s but there were also DOS ports.

Fun School 4 in particular has Teddy Bear themed levels

Comment: Looking at Fun School 4, the levels are called "Addition,
Teddy Paint,
Fun Train,
Teddy's House,
Teddy's Karaoke,
Teddy's Books". This sounds very accurate and covers pretty much every aspect I named in my question! So I'm inclined to believe this is correct, but I won't mark as accepted until I've tried it out to verify. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: We had many of these titles for our Amstrad CPC, and trains and teddies were definitely included.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Stickybear series? https://archive.org/search.php?query=4am%20stickybear

They were primarily for the Apple II but some were ported to the IBM PC.